# Django 1.3 in appengine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Google appengine comes with django 0.96 by default. I am using app-engine-patch to use django 1.0 on GAE, I have heard about app-engine-nonrel. I am not sure how to use django 1.3 on GAE. Has anyone tried the same

Comment: be careful with Google limitations on GAE. You can only have 3000 files (I think) uploaded on your app and with Djangos contrib folders you can easily go over this

Comment: i am using zip import. I don't think that will be a problem ..

Comment: It's not such a good idea to zipimport django though. I was running in multiple problems when doing so in the past. Main problem is that locale/media/template files can not be read from zipfile. As far as I remember it failed for me already on syncdb stage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no standalone version for django 1.3 in appengine yet. You can use Django 1.0, 1.1 or 1.2 though if you want to (without app-engine-patch). See [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django) for more information.

About django-nonrel. It's great and is working with 1.3 already. If you follow the [guidelines](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengin) you are basically good to go. Keep in mind that you can only syncdb and createsuperuser with appengine via `manage.py remote`.

Comment: Small update: django-nonrel and django-appengine are not supported anymore. Since Google Appengine became more unattractive as a free hosting now it makes kind of sense.

Answer (score 5):

[Django 1.3 is now available for all Python runtimes](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.6.3_-_February_28,_2012)

(Sorry, Shay :) )

Comment: lol, serve me right for not double reading my answers :) you can remove the sorry part from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

GAE [Version 1.6.2](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.6.2_-_January_31,_2012) - January 31, 2012

> Django version 1.3 is now available in the Python 2.5 runtime.

Python 2.7 still remains in Django 1.2